# Heroku Database Upload to Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I want to upload a Database Dump to an Amazon s3 Bucket, but im quite not sure, how to do it.

I was searching for Tutorials and already got a Bucket and an IAM User. Just to be honest, i dont know how to create the script for uploading it. I'm working with Rails 5.

I'm not a Pro Developer, so maybe someone here can explain in many steps how to do it.

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: There are few different as for your exact solution please refer to https://pawelurbanek.com/heroku-postgresql-s3-backup

Answer (score 1):

Search for carrierwave gem. It is a file upload mechanism that supports Amazon S3. It might be a little complicated for you because it has a lot of configs to set.

reference: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.1/CarrierWave/Storage/S3

Comment: This looks good! But how can i create and download a database backup with a schedular out of heroku?

Comment: you can just use ruby exec command to dump database.  something like: exec 'mysqldump -u username -ppassword --databases databasename'

Comment: Can i do this inside of a worker? I mean, i want to automate this.

Comment: yep. there is no problem implementing it inside a worker